# Spring Security define custom anonymous principal

Tags: authentication, spring-security

How to make a custom unique anonymous principal to each anonymous instead of default `anonymousUser`?

For example do increment `anonymousUser1`, `anonymousUser2`.

I guess I have to override `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter`.

Is it correct way?

```
@Component
public class AnonymousAuthentication extends AnonymousAuthenticationFilter {

    private AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest, ?> authenticationDetailsSource = new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource();

    private static int anonymSuffix = 0;

    public AnonymousAuthentication() {
        super("key");
    }

    @Override
    protected Authentication createAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
            anonymSuffix++;
            AnonymousAuthenticationToken auth = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken("",
                "anonym" + anonymSuffix, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ANONYMOUS"));
            auth.setDetails(authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));

        return auth;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, be more specific. So that I can help you.

Comment: How can I be more specific? I need to give an unique name (principal) to each anonymous entity being logged.

Comment: What is the point of this? A user will get a different "anonymousN" when they come back...

Comment: Let's say I need to determine anonymous principle for a chat room. In chat there could be members or anonymous users, so, I wanted to give them a name.

Comment: The code looks correct, but then depending on how you use the user in session.

Comment: you could just log them in ( SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication() ) with a random username